# How can I access Rails mountable engine helper method in main app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have written a helper method in my Rails mountable engine and I want to know how can I access that helper method in my main Rails app.

Comment: What is the output of your `rake routes`

Comment: do you want me to check wether engine is listing in it or not ? if so yes it is listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for this and here is my findings :)

for accessing rails mountable engines helper method add this lines to mountable engine's `lib/my_engine/engine.rb` file

```
config.before_initialize do
  ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do
    helper MyEngine::Engine.helpers
  end
end
```

Comment: watch out for `NameError: uninitialized constant YourGem::ApplicationHelper`, it happened during a production deployment while localhost was fine